# Why should I (or anyone) become a moderator? What will I be in for?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Please migrate to the big meta if it belongs there...

I'm getting notices about the nomination phase of the current election ("This community needs your help!") and my eligibility to self-nominate.

Aside from the introductions and questionnaire responses from the two current nominees, there's not much information that would indicate the level of involvement required from a mod, especially the anticipated/expected/required time commitment for moderating music.stackexchange.com in particular.

We might get more nominees if people know what they're in for.

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote.

Comment: Whenever I get one of those, I attribute it to one of the many downvote trolls I presume to haunt the site.

Answer (score 10):

I think it's a fair question, personally, and suitable for our Meta since the expectations here are likely different than they would be at some of the more popular sites.

In my experience, it's not normally that much extra work. Those interested in pursuing the moderator position are typically already active in the Review Queues, so there's usually not much workload added in that arena since the user is already doing similar work.

The main time investment is a result of the larger issues: tricky Meta questions, reaching out to individual users, and, in extreme cases, dealing with particularly difficult users (like the instance that Dom and Doktor Mayhem handled beautifully a few years ago).

All in all, for our site—and recognizing that our traffic has declined over the past few years—I'd estimate less than an extra hour each week. But I'd be interested in what Dom and Doktor Mayhem have to say; perhaps my time commitment would have been more had my circumstances been different.

Lastly, I'd be remiss not to mention the moral/philosophical aspect of moderating at Stack Exchange. In light of recent events, many moderators have stepped down, gone on strike, etc. as a form of protest. I think any interested moderator candidate should be aware of SE's recent history to make sure they would be comfortable with being a moderator for this site.

Comment: I think you have pretty much nailed it. Time commitment can vary a lot between mods, and over time - I fit mine around day job commitments, with review a few times a day - on this site about an hour a week seems about right. Others may do all theirs in one chunk.

Comment: Which instance did Dom and Doktor Mayhem handle?

Comment: @mathlander An especially troublesome user who neglected to learn from their mistakes and then tried to circumvent bans with several additional and anonymous accounts. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337396/388437